# How to put 2 video side by side and create chunks of given duration?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to combine 2 commands

1. **Merge a webcam capture and a desktop capture side-by-side:**

   ```
   ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 \
   -f x11grab -framerate 100 -video_size 1600x900 -i :0.0 \
   -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:900:0:(oh-ih)/2[left];[left][1:v]hstack" \
   output.avi
   ```
2. **Create chunks of a duration  from 1 video:**

   ```
   ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -f segment -segment_time 1 -strftime 1 '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts'
   ```

What is the proper way of merging those 2 commands in order to have at the end chunks of a video comprised of those 2 videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine them:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 \
-f x11grab -framerate 100 -video_size 1600x900 -i :0.0 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:900:0:(oh-ih)/2[left];[left][1:v]hstack,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -f segment -segment_time 1 -strftime 1 '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts'
```

Comment: My webcam video looses its aspect ratio. How to solve the problem?

Comment: @UdayReddy You should ask a new question on this site. Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: I've posted my question(https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115811/merge-and-concat-video-using-ffmpeg). See if you can help.